# get file size before upload with javascript

Tags: javascript

this is html code :

```
<form method="POST" action="http://my-site.com/send-file" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="6Yav0H6Cyp62Rhr6uAAEefzL7Yq0BqIHfhuYwzy4"> 
      <label for="file">File</label>
      <input id="iefile" name="img" type="file">
      <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

this is js code :

```
 $('form').submit(function(e) { // capture submit
        e.preventDefault();
        size=$(this).find("input:file").files[0].size ;
        alert(size);
}
```

but in console this error displayed :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve properties of DOM elements you should use `.prop()`:

```
$(this).find("input:file").prop('files')[0].size
```

This is because `$(this).find()` returns a jQuery object and not the DOM element directly. Alternatively, you can treat the results as an array and use the first element like so:

```
$(this).find("input:file")[0].files[0].size
```

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873397/get-file-size-before-upload-with-javascript#comment44149007_27873407) in the comments, you should also make sure a file was selected first:

```
var f = $(this).find("input:file")[0].files[0];
if (f) {
    // do something with f.size
}
```

Comment: And hopefully they picked a file before they submitted or that is an error.